# When is Poker Face set?

Tags: poker-face

Are there any hints in the show or from the show's creators about when the events of *[Poker Face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_Face_(TV_series))* (2023) took place?

It is revealed in the Season 1 finale (Episode 10) that at least 368 days have passed between Episode 1 and the end of Episode 9. The Season 1 finale also provides a timeline of when the other episodes took place relative to Episode 1. However, I'm not sure when Episode 1 took place exactly.

The line "George Soros' role in orchestrating the plandemic" (referencing the COVID-19 pandemic) in Episode 3 suggests that *Poker Face* is set in 2020 or later. The lack of people shown wearing masks leads me to believe that Episode 1 took place sometime in 2022 or 2023. If I'm not mistaken, mask mandates in the United States ended in 2022, which could explain why no one was shown wearing masks.

Although the timeframe is likely to be in 2022 or 2023, I'd like to know if the setting has a more specific date.

##### When is *Poker Face* set?

Answer (score 3):

The show appears to be set approximately in the modern day but has a deliberate 1970s aesthetic and is full of *inconsistent* timeline clues.

In episode 1 Charlie is referred to as "a regular Michael Westin" referring to the lead in a tv show called Burn Notice (which ran 2007-2013) and Charlie's friend's pictures were trapped on an iPhone with face ID login (a feature introduced in 2017).

But then in episode 2 (allegedly a couple months later) the reason for going on the roof was to view a major Leonids meteor shower event which "only happens every 33 years". The last such event was in 2002 so either the character is mistaken or...we're back in 2002 now.

The fashion and cars and title font/color shown are all from the 1970s.